# What's the reason why second parameter of a function is always being treated as 1?

Tags: python, python-3.9

My goal is to create a dice roller which lets the user choose both the number of dice and number of sides.

The problem started when I made it possible for the user to go through the process again (select number of dice and of sides). Now it doesn't display the result of anything besides the first die and, when the user types "n" and function breaks, sometimes it does, and sometimes it keeps going. This last part makes sense because the function "start" comes next. I haven't figured a way to truly finish running the script.

```
from random import randint


def dice(n_sides, n_dice):
    rolls = []
    for i in range(n_dice):
        # variable "roll" generates random number between 1 and user input
        roll = randint(1, n_sides)
        # variable "roll" is appended to the previously created empty list "rolls"
        rolls.append(roll)
        # enumerates however many results there was
        i += 1
        # prints the end result to the user
        print("Result", i, ":", roll)

        choice = input("Do you want to roll the dice again? (y/n)")

        # if user input is "y", start over by running function "start"
        if  choice.lower() == 'y':
            start()
        # uses lower() so that lower case is allowed
        elif choice.lower() == 'n':
            # break terminates function
            break


def start():
    print()
    try:
        print("How many sides your dice has?")
        n_sides = int(input().lower())
    # if something other than integers are typed by user
    except ValueError:
        print("This is not a whole number.")

    try:
        print("How many dice do you want to use?")
        n_dice = int(input().lower())
    # if something other than integers are typed by user
    except ValueError:
        print("This is not a whole number.")

    dice(n_sides, n_dice)


start()
```

Comment: On your first iteration, you always either call `start()` or `break`... why is that *inside the loop*?

Comment: You're calling these recursively.  That's not a good solution.  `dice` should just do the dice stuff.  If should be up to `start` (or the caller of `start`) do decide how often to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a better way to organize this.  Have each function do one thing.  When it has done its one thing, let someone else make the decisions.

Also, it's pointless to call `lower()` when all you want is integers.

```
from random import randint

def dice(n_sides, n_dice):
    rolls = []
    for i in range(n_dice):
        # variable "roll" generates random number between 1 and user input
        roll = randint(1, n_sides)
        # variable "roll" is appended to the previously created empty list "rolls"
        rolls.append(roll)
        # prints the end result to the user
        print("Result", i+1, ":", roll)
    return rolls

def round():
    print()
    try:
        n_sides = int(input("How many sides your dice has?"))
    # if something other than integers are typed by user
    except ValueError:
        print("This is not a whole number.")
        continue

    try:
        n_dice = int(input("How many dice do you want to use?"))
    # if something other than integers are typed by user
    except ValueError:
        print("This is not a whole number.")
        continue

    print(dice(n_sides, n_dice))

while True:
    round()
    choice = input("Do you want to roll the dice again? (y/n)")
    if  choice.lower() == 'n':
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is, you have n dices each having m sides and the user will roll all the dices per input.
Your code has the bug inside `dice(n_sides, n_dice):` function as you are executing all the statements in the for loop which is running same times the number of dices. Remember, **indentation is important in python**

Also, while you're taking input, you can use a while loop to force the user to input a valid number like this:

```
isNumeric = False
while(isNumeric == False):
    try:
        print("How many sides your dice has?")
        n_sides = int(input().lower())
        isNumeric = True
# if something other than integers are typed by user
    except ValueError:
        print("This is not a whole number.")

isNumeric = False
while(isNumeric == False):
    try:
        print("How many dice do you want to use?")
        n_dice = int(input().lower())
        isNumeric = True
# if something other than integers are typed by user
    except ValueError:
        print("This is not a whole number.")
```

To remove the bug in your dice function, you can do as follows:

```
def dice(n_sides, n_dice):
    rolls = []
    for i in range(n_dice):
        # variable "roll" generates random number between 1 and user input
        roll = randint(1, n_sides)
        # variable "roll" is appended to the previously created empty list "rolls"
        rolls.append(roll)
        # prints the end result to the user
        print("Result of Dice Number", i+1, ":", roll)

    choice = input("Do you want to roll the dice again? (y/n)")

    # if user input is "y", start over by running function "start"
    if  choice.lower() == 'y':
        start()
    # uses lower() so that lower case is allowed
```

This will smoothly solve all of your problems!

Comment: Thanks, that was also a great answer!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would use `exit()` instead of `break`. Break can be used in loops (see here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue)
Secondly, use a while loop for the yes or no question, like:

```
    while True:
        a = input("Do you want to roll the dice again? (y/n)")
        if a == "y":
            start()
            continue
        elif a == "n":
            exit()
        else:
            print("Enter either y/n")
```

So if you don't want to change the logic of the code:

```
from random import randint

def dice(n_sides, n_dice):
    rolls = []
    for i in range(n_dice):
        roll = randint(1, n_sides)
        rolls.append(roll)
        i += 1
    print("Result", i, ":", roll)
    while True:
        a = input("Do you want to roll the dice again? (y/n)")
        if a == "y":
            start()
            continue
        elif a == "n":
            exit()
        else:
            print("Enter either y/n")

def start():
    while True:
        try:
            print("How many sides your dice has?")
            n_sides = int(input())
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("This is not a whole number.")
    while True:
        try:
            print("How many dice do you want to use?")
            n_dice = int(input())
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("This is not a whole number.")
    dice(n_sides, n_dice)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

Edit:
you need to import exit to do this: `from sys import exit`

Comment: Both your answer and the provided link helped, thank you!